ng2-pdf-viewer and pdfjs-dist
In angular 15.2.9 application I am using ng2-pdf-viewer , pdfjs-dist for loading and edit a Pdf.
I am using  "ng2-pdf-viewer": "^9.1.5" version.
I want suitable version of pdfjs-dist.
I tried     "pdfjs-dist": "^2.5.207" but it is not working.

Try "pdfjs-dist": "~2.14.305",
package.json of ng2-pdf-viewer 9.1.5.
